# How to change the background color of a clicked button in android when background tint attribute is default in button?

Tags: java, android-studio, button, onclick, background-color

```
      These are the attributes I have used in this button.
        I have also created one XML file button_round_corner_view.
           
           <Button
                        android:id="@+id/true_button"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner_view"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="True"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:backgroundTint="#F8F4F4"
                        />
                
    This is the XML file attribute that I have created for a better button look.
please provide me the best answer for this problem and also tell me how to stop
```

the background tint attribute which applied by default on the button

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
        
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
        
            <!-- This is the border color -->
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/purple_700"/> 
      
            <!-- This is the background color -->
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white"/> 

        </shape>
```

BackgroundTint attribute in a button is the default. And I want to change the background color of my button when the user clicks the button.
How to achieve this. please help me.

Comment: You want to change colour when ever the use touches the button right for some effects?

Comment: For Example, when the user click the true or false button and the answer is right or wrong, according to the situation for the right answer i want to change the button background color as green, and for the wrong answer i want to change the button background color as red

Comment: background Tint attribute is default

Comment: Ok I got it let me write the code and post in answer

Answer (score 0):

For Example Lets say there button1 so it will be like

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Answer.equals("Correct")){
                button1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkGreen));
                
            }else if(Answer.equals("InCorrect")){
                button1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
                
            }
        });
```

You can do something like this. This is how you change colour of a button.

Comment: you are late, i have got the answer yesterday, the simple solution put backgroundTint attribute value of a button ="@null" and put the if else condition just like you have written above and hence the case solved. Thanks for giving your time.

Comment: i have used set background property of get drawable and i have also created xml file in drawable directory. my solution is different from yours.

Comment: Oh nice glad to know that.